# Upgrading view engine to Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I wan't to upgrade my MVC.Net site to 3.0 and also upgrade my asp.net view engine to the Razor.

I have seen that e.g. master pages look a bit different, so are there any tutorials on how to do a switch from asp.net to Razor?

Also how can I update the view engine for an existing site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Gu has a good [series of blog posts](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx) about how Razor layouts work.

Comment: I know I need to replace all the tags and modify them to use Razor, I was more wondering if the structure of the files should be changed, or if there was anything I should take in consideration when trying to change the view engine.

Comment: I used a step-by-step upgrade involving a bunch of web.config changes to upgrade an MVC 2 project and its views to MVC 3 with Razor, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @Dofs, the structure of the files doesn't change much but there are specifics. Master pages have been replaced by layouts, you have the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file which is common for all views, there is no longer distinction between view and a partial view (ie. aspx vs ascx), ...

Answer (score 7):

I'd also suggest reading the blog posts by ScottGu as they're the best documentation that we've got for Razor.

I can suggest you try this tool for converting the bulk of the views (at least the simple ones):

https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter

But don't get me wrong - the conversion still requires human input and lots of it. Detailed knowledge of the Razor conventions is very much important.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I just saw the post today about the tool!